# Can I run Firebase Cloud Messaging entirely in a web service worker?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-worker

**TLDR:** Is it a problem if you don't have FCM code running in the foreground of the application? Are there any problems that may arise from having everything in a web worker?

---

I have the following service worker:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({ ... });

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    console.log('Service worker activating...');

    // Add the public key generated from the console here.
    messaging.usePublicVapidKey();

    // Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
    // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
    messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
        console.log("currentToken", currentToken);

        if (currentToken) {
            // sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
        } else {
            console.error('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    });

    messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
        console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    });
});
```

If this service worker is started like so:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('js/service-worker.js')
        .then(registration => {
            console.log('Service Worker is registered', registration);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Registration failed:', err);
        });
    });
}
```

Is it a problem if the `onTokenRefresh` callback is never handled, given that this can only be handled in the foreground.

Does this setup of FCM seem correct?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use specify an existing service worker have named `js/service-worker.js`?

The Firebase messaging default service worker file name is `firebase-messaging-sw.js`.

If you want to use specify an existing service worker then you should specify an existing service worker with useServiceWorker.

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_foreground
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#useserviceworker

> your app must define the Firebase messaging service worker in firebase-messaging-sw.js. Alternatively, you can specify an existing service worker with useServiceWorker.